# how to populate the state and city in my project without using AJAX and refresh page?

Tags: javascript, database, struts-1

I am looking a sample for the functionality where there are 2 drop downs. One is 1 is State/Province and the 2rd is City. Based on the state drop down selection, city drop down values should be populated.

I need sample database design also....

Could anyone please help me out on getting a sample for this.

Regards
padman..

Comment: Btw, in general you'll want to accept answers, or vote them up, if they directly address your question.

Answer (score 0):

With neither Ajax nor refreshes? Bad idea, unless you have a very limited number of state/city combinations--otherwise the HTML/JavaScript you send will be huge.

Otherwise it's a simple dependent select, which is searchable on the web. The nutshell version is that when your state changes, you take the value of the selected state option, use it to look up cities in a map of state id => cities, and use the cities collection to populate the second select box.

The state/cities JavaScript structure is created on the server side using whatever template mechanism the rest of the app uses (I assume JSP or Velocity since you're using Struts 1).

**DB** DB design for what? States and cities? Have a table of states. Have a table of cities with a state id foreign key.

Comment: OK, Dave thanks for reply i just looking a an idea that's all. I am new to software that's why these question . could you send your mail id for my feature query?

Comment: No, unless I can bill you :) Places like [javaranch.com](http://javaranch.com) (more beginner-friendly, IMO) and SO are "staffed" by volunteers that are more than happy to help with specific questions.